# Pardiso cannot find License File

Tags: ubuntu, pardiso

My Pardiso C code compiles on my UBUNTU system but when I try to run the code I get:

License error. Wrong user license
user name: root
directory: /root
wrong username or hostname.

I have tried a new license code and putting the pardiso.lic file in the run directory, home and root directories but no luck.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the PARDISO library from [pardiso-project](https://pardiso-project.org)?

As the [Pardiso manual](https://pardiso-project.org/manual/manual.pdf) states you either have to put the license file in the home directory of the user running the code or in the directory running your application. There is the third option of specifying the environment variable `PARDISO_LIC_PATH` and putting the pardiso.lic file there.

In either case - the license file must have been obtained for the user running the code (the `ẁhoami` on your command line if your user is running the code).

For me, all these work (with the current Pardiso).

As from your description it seems like you already tried the home directory.
I have a few guesses as to what could be at fault:

Did you run your code as root? The fact that PARDISO is looking for a license file in /root let's me think that - did you specify the root-user when you downloaded the license? Or did you put the suggested `whoami`?

Are there any trailing whitespaces/newlines in your pardiso.lic file?

Hope this helps (it is a bit late).

Flusslauf